# Taking a picture and storing it to internal storage

Tags: android

I'm trying to take a picture and when the user clicks the button, I want to save the picture to the internal storage. I will be testing on a tablet which does not have an sd card. I'm also new to taking pictures on android and the web has been no help with trying to find what specific code I need to write it to somewhere other than an sd card. Here is what my camera.java looks like.

```
package com.test;

import com.test.R;

import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;

import android.app.Activity;

import android.hardware.Camera;
import android.hardware.Camera.PictureCallback;
import android.hardware.Camera.ShutterCallback;

import android.os.Bundle;

import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.FrameLayout;

public class camera extends Activity
{
    private static final String TAG = "CameraDemo";
        Camera camera;
        Preview preview;
        Button buttonClick;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.camera);

        preview = new Preview(this);
        ((FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.preview)).addView(preview);

        buttonClick = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonClick);
        buttonClick.setOnClickListener( new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                preview.camera.takePicture(shutterCallback, rawCallback, jpegCallback);
            }
        });

        Log.d(TAG, "onCreate'd");
    }


    ShutterCallback shutterCallback = new ShutterCallback() {
        public void onShutter() {
            Log.d(TAG, "onShutter'd");
        }
    };

    /** Handles data for raw picture */
    PictureCallback rawCallback = new PictureCallback() {
        public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) {
            Log.d(TAG, "onPictureTaken - raw");
        }
    };

    /** Handles data for jpeg picture */
    PictureCallback jpegCallback = new PictureCallback() {
        public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) {
            FileOutputStream outStream = null;
            try {
                // write to local sandbox file system
                outStream = camera.this.openFileOutput(String.format("%d.jpg", System.currentTimeMillis()), 0); 
                // Or write to sdcard
                //outStream = new FileOutputStream(String.format("/sdcard/%d.jpg", System.currentTimeMillis()));    
                outStream.write(data);
                outStream.close();
                Log.d(TAG, "onPictureTaken - wrote bytes: " + data.length);
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
            }
            Log.d(TAG, "onPictureTaken - jpeg");
        }
    };

}
```

Comment: FYI, Most devices which do not support a removable external storage still have an "external storage" allocated in soldered-down flash which can be found via the api calls.  Though there may be exceptions, and there is certainly the case of devices which depend on a removable card which may not be present, as well as the case where the storage partition is not available to apps because it is being made remotely accessible to a connected pc.

Answer (score 2):

It's not really clear what kind of problem you're getting with that code.  The way you're opening the file seems fine, so maybe it's behaving in another way that's incorrect?

This page in the Android document has details about using the different kinds of storage available to your application: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html

In particular, the section about [saving files that should be shared](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#SavingSharedFiles) might be useful to your situation. It references "external storage" but many devices simulate external storage using internal storage, so as a developer you don't need to worry about it.

If you want the picture to be viewable in the system's Gallery app, you can add it to media scanning using [MediaScannerConnection.scanFile](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaScannerConnection.html#scanFile%28android.content.Context,%20java.lang.String%5B%5D,%20java.lang.String%5B%5D,%20android.media.MediaScannerConnection.OnScanCompletedListener%29). That may not work, though, if you are storing files in your app's private storage with `openFileOutput`.

Answer (score 0):

You can see this [Picture Demo](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-advandroid/blob/master/Camera/Picture/src/com/commonsware/android/picture/PictureDemo.java) sample from CommonsAware's Github page, it might be useful to you.